# Non local keyword doesn't seems to be working

Tags: python-3.x, scope

I expect the variables inside foo to change as I am using nonlocal keyword in the method bar. My understanding is that the variables a,b,c are no longer local in bar and they are just an assignment to the variables a,b,c in foo and therefore the values should change in foo.
I don't see that happening when I run the below code in python3. Wondering what am I missing

Below is the output

```
From foo
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30

From bar
a = 11
b = 12
c = 19

From chu
a = 200
b = 300
c = 500
```

Here is the code

```
def foo():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = 30
    print("From {func}\na = {a}\nb = {b}\nc = {c}\n".format(func="foo", a=a, b=b, c=c))

    def bar():
        nonlocal a
        nonlocal b
        nonlocal c
        a = 11
        b = 12
        c = 19
        print("From {func}\na = {a}\nb = {b}\nc = {c}\n".format(func="bar", a=a, b=b, c=c))

        def chu():
            a = 200
            b = 300
            c = 500
            print("From {func}\na = {a}\nb = {b}\nc = {c}\n".format(func="chu",a=a,b=b,c=c))
        chu()
    bar()
foo()
```

Comment: You are printing `a`, `b` and `c` immediately after assigning to them in the same scope. No matter how `a`, `b` and `c` are scoped, you will get the values you assigned immediately prior. I am not sure what else you expect to happen.

Comment: Did that answer your question? I expected you to describe your expected output in more detail.